# How do I turn off a task if another task is assigned work?

Tags: task-management

Based on a template. Is there a way to turn off a task if another task has been assigned work? I am in a company that uses massive templates and it would be great to turn off those tasks automatically which won't be performed because of work type. By the way, I don't have enterprise fields.

Comment: What software do you use?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what software you are using (I assume MP).

Probably your best solution is to bring this to your BA (Analyst), EA (Architect), or PM superior, and have them reconsider workflow. If you have full authority, I would say what you're actually after is the creation of multiple templates. Or, the template should be re-arranged with hierarchy based on task relationship.